# thymealf iteration of an iteration

Tags: java, spring, foreach, thymeleaf

In my domain I have a `Commessa` that contain a List of `programmazioneTransient` that contain a list of `varieTransient`.

With thymeleaf I create a view that show every element of the second list, and run perfectly. Now I added the loop for showing the list of varieTransient but I have this error:

> Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating
>   SpringEL expression:
>   "programmazioneTransient+${prgStat.index}.varieTransient" (template:
>   "views/programmazione/show" - line 92, col 19)    at
>   org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
>   ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
>   ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
>   ~[thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]  ... 102 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating SpringEL expression:
>   "programmazioneTransient+${prgStat.index}.varieTransient" (template:
>   "views/programmazione/show" - line 92, col 19)    at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]

My **html** page is the follow:

```
<th:block th:each="prg, prgStat : *{programmazioneTransient}">
        <tr th:id="riga+${prgStat.index}">
            <td scope="col" style="width: 15%!important;">
                <input type="text" th:id="sperimentatore+${prgStat.index}" th:name="programmazioneTransient[+${prgStat.index}+].sperimentatore" class="text-center form-control-plaintext" readonly="readonly" th:value="${#strings.capitalizeWords(prg.sperimentatoreTransient)}"></input>
            </td>
            <td scope="col" style="width: 15%!important;">
                <input type="text" th:id="aiutoSperimentatore+${prgStat.index}" th:name="programmazioneTransient[+${prgStat.index}+].aiutoSperimentatore" class="text-center form-control-plaintext" readonly="readonly" th:value="${#strings.capitalizeWords(prg.aiutoSperimentatoreTransient)}"></input>
            </td>
                            ...
            <th:block th:each="v, vInd : *{programmazioneTransient+${prgStat.index}.varieTransient}" > 
                <td scope="col" >
                    <input type="number" th:id="v.quantita+*{#lists.size(programmazioneTransient)}" th:name="varieTransient[+${vInd.index}+].numeroProgrammate" class="text-center form-control-plaintext" readonly="readonly" th:value="varieTransient[+${vInd.index}+].numeroProgrammate"></input>
                </td>
            </th:block> 
        </tr> 
</th:block>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What you try to do with this line : *{programmazioneTransient+${prgStat.index}.varieTransient}

Comment: Basing on your question, it looks like you try to make sum on list and element

Comment: @RafałSokalski I want to see at position ${prgStat.index} the Element varieTransient, I try to use *{programmazioneTransient[+${prgStat.index}+] but give me an error on `[ `

Comment: Don't you miss there [] to get list element ?

Comment: @RafałSokalski give me error..

Comment: how did you change it using [] ?

Comment: Obtain this error: `Unexpected token. Expected 'rsquare(])' but was 'lcurly({)'`

Comment: show whole line that you corrected

Comment: I need to loop in list2[i].list3 `<th:block th:each="v, vInd : *{programmazioneTransient[${prgStat.index}].varieTransient}" > `

Comment: Try to add double underscore before $ and after first }

Comment: Thanks.. I had resolved using this in each command:  `${prg.varieTransient}`, prg is the element of the first loop.

Comment: Did you try with underscore ?

Comment: No, is not necessary. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to index, why not just use the local variable?

```
<th:block th:each="prg, prgStat : *{programmazioneTransient}">
    .
    .
    .
    <th:block th:each="v, vInd : ${prg.varieTransient}">
        .
        .
        .
    </th:block>
</th:block>
```

If you do want to use the index, you should remember that in general, you shouldn't nest `${...}` expressions -- except in special cases.  That expression would look like this:

```
<th:block th:each="v, vInd : *{programmazioneTransient[prgStat.index].varieTransient}">
    .
    .
    .
</th:block>
```

Comment: It's exactly the way that I follow. Thanks